# How do I install composer in container of docker?

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, virtual-machine, laradock

I am new at docker and docker-compose and I am developing a Laravel-project on docker and docker-compose with Laradock as following a tutorial(not sure whether It is a correct way or not to refer this situation though).

I want to install the `composer` in this environment to be able to use the  `composer` command.

As a matter of fact, I wanted to do seeding to put data into DB that I made by `php artisan make:migrate` but this error appeared.

```
include(/var/www/laravel_practice/vendor/composer/../../database/seeds/AdminsTableSeeder.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

So I googled this script to find a solution that will solve the error then I found it.
It says, "Do `composer dump-autoload` and try seeding again", so I followed it then this error appeared.

```
bash: composer: command not found
```

Because I have not installed composer into docker-container.
My docker's condition is like this now.
・workspace
・mysql
・apache
・php-fpm
Since I have not installed the `composer`, I have to install it into docker-container to solve the problem, BUT I have no idea how to install it into docker-container.

So could anyone tell me how to install `composer` into docker-container?
Thank you.

here is the `laradock/mysql/Dockerfile` and `laravelProject/docker-compose.yml`.

```
ARG MYSQL_VERSION=5.7
FROM mysql:${MYSQL_VERSION}

LABEL maintainer="Mahmoud Zalt <mahmoud@zalt.me>"

#####################################
# Set Timezone
#####################################

ARG TZ=UTC
ENV TZ ${TZ}
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone && chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf

CMD ["mysqld"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "6603:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laravelProject
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    command: mysqld --sql-mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci

  web:
    image: arbiedev/php-nginx:7.1.8
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

volumes:
  db:
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @prithajnath Thank you for your advice. I modified it and how is it now?

Comment: Much better. Do you happen to have the relevant Dockerfile that you used to create your image/container?

Comment: what is your base image- can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: @prithajnath  I added information about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build your own image and use it in your Docker compose file.

```
FROM php:7.2-alpine3.8

RUN apk update
RUN apk add bash
RUN apk add curl

# INSTALL COMPOSER
RUN curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN alias composer='php composer.phar'

# INSTALL NGINX
RUN apk add nginx
```

I used the PHP alpine image as my base image because it's lightweight, so you might have to install other dependencies yourself. In your docker-compose file

```
web:
  build: path/to/your/Dockerfile/directory
  image: your-image-tag
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  volumes:
    - ./www:/var/www
    - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!
I have a question. You said like, "write these code in docker-compose file". Does it mean "docker-compose.yml"?

Comment: @pop Yep. I meant the docker-compse.yml file

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
FROM php:8.0.2-apache
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-client libxml2-dev
RUN apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get autoclean
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql xml
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

the argument [**COPY --from=**](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

RUN php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add bash
RUN alias composer='php /usr/bin/composer'
```